# Is it possible for an app to disallow custom keyboard in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8

With custom keyboards in iOS 8, there is a potential risk that users of your app unknowingly have installed a malicious custom keyboard that performs keylogging and whatnot.

This can be detrimental to apps that deal with sensitive data input.

To reduce this risk, it would be nice if there was a way for iOS8-apps to disallow the use of custom keyboards.

Is this possible?

Comment: Its down to the user to risk assess keyboards as far as i am aware - inform the user of the risks of inputting sensitive data from your app in a non-intrusive manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use custom keyboard for [secure input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) :

> There are certain text input objects that your custom keyboard is not
>   eligible to type into. First is any secure text input object. Such an
>   object is defined by its secureTextEntry property being set to YES and
>   is distinguished by presenting typed characters as dots.

So getting password should not be possible.
Also iOS will prompt the user if a keyboard want internet access, this to make keyloggers more obvious.

To disable custom keyboard in your app completely override the [`application:shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier {
   // Disallow custom keyboards
   return ![extensionPointIdentifier isEqualToString:UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, An app developer can elect to reject the use of all custom keyboards in their app. There are many concern like you have already take care by Apple before allowing this feature like it's just an option, not allow to enter data into secrete field and many. For more details read here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

Comment: And how would the said app developer go about electing this...?

Comment: The guide explain little about it and about how user can switch from main keyboard to other as i found. but I dont have any practical explanation for now about app election for keyboard.